# Retrieving warnings generated in a knitr session

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a long R Markdown script that generates more than fifty knitr errors.  It produces a .pptx file that requires repairs (although I cannot see what needed repair). Occasionally PowerPoint renames the file based on the first title slide.  The knitting session produces a warning message that invites me so inspect them by entering `warnings()`.  Insofar as the knitr session is in an environment invisible to me, typing `warnings()` is not helpful.

> Output created: demo.pptx There were 50 or more warnings (use
>   warnings() to see the first 50)

I cannot give a succinct, reproducible example that produces knitr warnings, but I can tell you that they come from caret and gbm which spit out **lots** of formatted output (black) and unformatted messages (red) and even unwanted plots, despite the default setting of verbose = FALSE.

Here is the head of my .rmd file:

````
---
title: "Demo of knitr warnings when making Powerpoint"
author: "author name"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
---
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=10, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache=FALSE)
```

```{r setup}   
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(knitr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rmarkdown))
```
````

How can I discover the environment in which knitr executed, so I can access the warnings?  When I tried to reproduce the warnings, I noted that the warnings generated by my code apparently aren't being appended to the *last.warnings* list.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the warning you should be able to set `warning=TRUE` in the global options and just review them in the output PPT. Use it for debugging and once you are satisfied with the output you can change it back to `warning=FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Run knitr using `rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd")` and it will run in the current session. Then warnings() will work.

For example, I didn't see any warnings from your code, but when I added

```
for ( i in 1:100)
  warning(i)
```

to the code chunk, I got a message like yours.  So I used the idea above, and saw

```
> rmarkdown::render("~/temp/Untitled.Rmd")


processing file: Untitled.Rmd
  |................                                                 |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................................                                 |  50%
label: global_options (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.................................................                |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: setup

output file: Untitled.knit.md

'/Applications/RStudio 2.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc' +RTS -K512m -RTS Untitled.utf8.md --to pptx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output Untitled.pptx --slide-level 2 

Output created: Untitled.pptx
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 1
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 2
3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 3
4: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 4
5: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 5
6: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 6
7: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 7
8: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 8
9: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 9
10: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 10
11: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 11
12: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 12
13: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 13
14: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 14
15: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 15
16: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 16
17: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 17
18: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 18
19: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 19
20: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 20
21: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 21
22: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 22
23: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 23
24: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 24
25: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 25
26: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 26
27: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 27
28: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 28
29: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 29
30: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 30
31: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 31
32: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 32
33: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 33
34: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 34
35: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 35
36: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 36
37: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 37
38: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 38
39: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 39
40: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 40
41: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 41
42: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 42
43: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 43
44: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 44
45: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 45
46: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 46
47: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 47
48: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 48
49: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 49
50: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  @user2554330 was right. `rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd")` works fine, in your own global environment.

If you are using RStudio, there are a few things to keep in mind:

- The source is whatever is saved to disk, so don't forget to save.
- You can check the environment with `knit.global()`. Whether you type the command or use the knit button -- which apparently spawns a new R session -- the result will be the same. You can get to the first, but not to the second.

  > environment: R_GlobalEnv
- You won't see the objects in your local environment until
  execution is complete.
- And PowerPoint doesn't start automatically.

Yes, all of the ugly warnings (in my case from gbm) are there.